# Multiple ajax calls crashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where I run multiple AJAX calls to retrieve various sections of a page. These calls happen every few mins/seconds and update respective sections.

When it happens the new elements come into DOM and some elements go away, etc. It all happen properly for the first few seconds and later things get messed up. Some calls just end up in just loading icon and do nothing. This is how I coded in my page:

```js
jQuery('body').on('click', '.markasread', function() {
  var message_id = jQuery(this).attr('message_id');
  if (message_id) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ACTION_URL,
        data: {
          "message_id": message_id
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          jQuery(this).html('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="" />');
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.html) {
            alert(data.html);
          }
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This is how I do all functions for each actions/auto refresh. Sometimes it just ends up showing loading. I'm wondering if am doing anything wrong? Is there any parameter that keeps AJAX calls from crashing with each other?

Comment: It sounds from your description of the calls 'happening every few seconds' that you're using AJAX polling. If that's the case it's possible you're choking up the server with requests. Check the network tab of the console next time a request fails to load to see how many are active. If it's more than 5 you're likely being limited by the number of concurrent connections a single user can have. Its for this reason that AJAX polling is a very bad idea. Look in to websockets or server sent events instead.

Comment: Also forever Frame on older versions of Internet Explorer. Nowadays though websockets or server sent events will **usually** be used by default on modern browsers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you will look into the websockets as alternative...